# No match for operator>> in QTCreator

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, reference, operators

I am new to C++ and I am having some problems with using the predefination of the 2 operators.

After some time I made the first one working, somehow, but I still get an error, when I try to use the second one(>>) in function fromStream, although I predefined them below.
The error is :

> core/src/SearchObject.cpp:55: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'QDataStream' and 'SearchObject*')
>        out >> this;

I think I got the logic wrong or something, I am so confused.

```
    void SearchObject::toStream(QDataStream in) {

        in << this;

    }


void SearchObject::fromStream(QDataStream out) {

    out >> this;

}
```

Here you can see some more of the code:

```
    SearchObject::SearchObject() {

    }

    QDataStream& operator >>(QDataStream &in, SearchObject &searchObject) {



   //read object from stream

        QString medium;
        int mediumIndex;
        Annotation *ann = new Annotation("", "");
        QRect *roi;
        QString source;

        //skip opening bracket
        in.skipRawData(1);

        in >> medium;
        searchObject.setMedium(medium);

        //skip coma
        in.skipRawData(2);

        in >> mediumIndex;
        searchObject.setMediumIndex(mediumIndex);

        in.skipRawData(2);

        in >> *ann;
        searchObject.setAnnotation(ann);

        in.skipRawData(2);

        in >> *roi;
        searchObject.setROI(roi);

        in.skipRawData(2);

        in >> source;
        searchObject.setSourceDataset(source);

        in.skipRawData(1);

        return in;
    }

    QDataStream& operator <<(QDataStream &out, SearchObject &searchObject) {

        //write object to stream
        out << "(" << searchObject.getMedium() << ", "
            << searchObject.getMediumIndex() << ", "
            << searchObject.getAnnotation() << ", "
            << searchObject.getROI() << ", "
            << searchObject.getSourceDataset() << ")";
        return out;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, `this` is a pointer — type `SearchObject*` (the star is "pointer").  The `operator>>` is expecting a reference — type `SearchObject&` (ampersand for "reference").  Try

```
out >> *this;
```

in `fromStream` (note the star before `this`).  `*this` is the object that `this` points to, so should match a `SearchObject&`.